# Controlling the visual presentation form/rendering of Arabic text on the web?

Tags: css, fonts, arabic, webfonts, arabic-support

[image: Picture 1]

and

[image: Picture 2]

are samples of the exact same Arabic text with the exact same font, rendered differently in respectively Chrome and Firefox.

The latter in Firefox is the most accurate rendering of the Arabic text `ٱلرَّحۡمَٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ`, which makes correct use of the ligature for the Arabic script.

I assume the correct Firefox rendering rules out the conclusion, that this is a 'font issue'..

So to the question: is it somehow possible with CSS to control/enforce ligature/presentation of Arabic script across different browsers, in this case, especially Chrome?

Sample HTML:

```
<div lang="ar" class="some_arabic_wrapper">ٱلرَّحۡمَٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ</div>
```

Sample CSS:

```
.some_arabic_wrapper {
    direction: rtl;
    font-family: 'MyWebFont';
    font-variant-ligatures: contextual;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    /* font-language-override: "ARB"; */
    /* unicode-bidi:initial; */
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us the name of the used font or post a running snippet? A lot of webfonts apparently have limited suoort for arabic ligatures - or none at all. So it's pretty hard to reproduce these issues.

Comment: Sure, it's a specific Arabic Quran font for displaying Quranic script, [link](https://qurancomplex.gov.sa/en/techquran/dev/). The above example is from the 'Hafs' font.

Answer (score 0):

HarfBuzz developer here. The text renders fine with latest HarfBuzz. What version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: I also tried in a recent Chrome on Linux and it renders fine.

Comment: Chrome `Version 114.0.5735.198 (Official Build) (arm64)` and Firefox `Version 115.0.2 (64-bit)`. This cause a problem: `<span>بِسۡمِ ٱللَّهِ ٱلرَّحۡمَٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ</span>` but somehow this work `<span>بِسۡمِ ٱللَّهِ ٱلرَّحۡمَٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ</span>`, i.e. the ligature /ha+mim+dagger alif/ shows up wrongly in Chrome as illustrated/described above

Comment: What's the difference between the two strings? I tried both in Chrome 114.0.5735.106 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Linux and they work fine. Can you setup a webpage with webfont that shows the problem?